# Missing permutation with itertools.permutations()

Tags: python-2.7, permutation, python-itertools

I was solving the itertools.permutations() code on Hackerrank at https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/itertools-permutations/problem and I came up with the following very simple code:

```
from itertools import permutations

to_perm, length = raw_input().split()
length = int(length)

res = permutations(to_perm, length)
new_res = []

for i in res:
    new_res = sorted(res)

for i in new_res:
    print "".join(i)
```

This is what I get as output:

```
AC
AH
AK
CA
CH
CK
HC
HK
KA
KC
KH
```

And this is my expected output:

```
AC
AH
AK
CA
CH
CK
HA
HC
HK
KA
KC
KH
```

You'll notice that I'm missing the permutation 'HA'.

My question is : Why am I missing this single permutation? And how can I solve this?

Comment: If you `print permutations(to_perm, length)` then `HA` is there. I'm not sure why you sort `res` over and over again (and overwriting `new_res`)

Comment: @DeepSpace I sort `res` only once because the problem requires the printed result to be sorted lexicographically.

Comment: It's been 2 days already. Can you guide me as to how to get more people to notice this? Most of the views on this page are by me only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what happens to `HA` in your code. This code outputs the correct result:

```
from itertools import permutations

to_perm, length = 'HACK', 2

res = permutations(to_perm, length)

res = sorted(res)

for perm in res:
    print ''.join(perm)
```

Outputs

```
AC
AH
AK
CA
CH
CK
HA
HC
HK
KA
KC
KH
```